# Has Directory Content Changed?

Tags: ruby, macos, file, directory

How can I check a directory to see if its contents has changed since a given point in time?

I don't need to be informed *when* it changes, or *what* has changed. I just need a way to check *if* it has changed.

Comment: Copy that directory to another place and them compare them. Or just check `mtime` of files.

Comment: It's a directory full of large assets, so copying it is not an option.  So there is no directory property indicating change? I would need to recursively check all files and sub directories and compare existance and `mtime`?

Comment: Solution below should work. Just store and compare a hash of a recursive glob() call to the directory in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to know if names have changed or files have been added/removed, you can try this:

```
Dir.glob('some_directory/**/*').hash
```

Just store and compare the hash values. You can obviously go further by getting more information out of a call to `ls`, for example, or out of File objects that represent each of the files in your directory structure, and hashing that.

```
Dir.glob('some_directory/**/*').map { |name| [name, File.mtime(name)] }.hash
```

**UM ACTUALLY** I'm being dumb and hash is only consistent for any one runtime environment of ruby. Let's use the standard `Zlib::crc32` instead, e.g.

```
Zlib::crc32(Dir.glob('some_directory/**/*').map { |name| [name, File.mtime(name)] }.to_s)
```

My concern is that this approach will be memory-hungry and slow if you're checking a very large filesystem. Perhaps globbing the entire structure and mapping it isn't the way--if you have a lot of subdirectories you could walk them recursively and calculate a checksum for each, then combine the checksums.

This might be better for larger directories:

```
Dir.glob('some_directory/**/*').map do |name| 
  s = [name, File.mtime(name)].to_s
  [Zlib::crc32(s), s.length]
end.inject(Zlib::crc32('')) do |combined, x| 
  Zlib::crc32_combine(combined, x[0], x[1])
end
```

This would be less prone to collisions:

```
Dir.glob('some_directory/**/*').map do |name| 
  [name, File.mtime(name)].to_s
end.inject(Digest::SHA512.new) do |digest, x| 
  digest.update x
end.to_s
```

Comment: I'm finding some strange inconsistencies with this approach. If I open IRB and execute `Dir.glob('some_directory/**/*').map { |name| [name, File.mtime(name)] }.hash` repeatedly, I get the same value every time. However, if I close IRB, reopen and do the same again, I get a different value (again repeated).

Comment: Hold tight and I'll look into it. I thought hash was consistent for any given input.

Comment: Ok, we'll need to generate a CRC digest instead. hash only has to be consistent for any given runtime environment. (This is why I like solving problems on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Works like a dream. Pretty minimal directory structure so no performance issues. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file at the point in time you wish to start monitoring, using any method you like, e.g.:

```
touch time_marker
```

Then, when you want to check if anything has been added, use "find" like this:

```
find . -newer time_marker
```

This will only tell you files that have been modified or added since time_marker was created - it won't tell you if anything has been deleted. If you want to look again at a future point, "touch" time_marker again to create a new reference point.

Answer (score 0):

I've amended this to include timestamp and file size.

```
dir_checksum = Zlib::crc32(Dir.glob(
  File.join(dispatch, '/**/*')).map { |path|
    path.to_s + "_" + File.mtime(path).to_s + "_" + File.size(path).to_s
  }.to_s)
```